# Why isn't current through D2 0 in LTSPICE?

Tags: ltspice

[image]

The current through d2 should b zero as it is reverse biased. Why dosen't ltspice software
show zero current?

-
If I am doing somethin wrong then kindly make correction and tell me what to do to get zero current in both D1 and D2?

Comment: There is such a thing as *[reverse leakage current](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_leakage_current)*

Comment: What *does* it show?

Comment: The question assumes zero current in reverse (incorrect) but doesn't state what that current is. The answer accepted alludes to this but still no further comment from the questioner as to what level of current was seen. I'm voting to close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without running your circuit to check, it is usual to expect leakage current in bipolar devices, and silicon diodes are p type and n type, hence the bipolar name. When one diode is reversed biased, impurities in the silicon structure allow a very small current to flow through the device. This current is very temperature sensitive. In a circuit such as this I would expect the reverse bias leakage current to be micro amps or less.